# Please merge [as400] and [iseries] into [ibm-i] on SO

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

IBM's marketing department went seriously astray with renaming the platform every other week.

Can we merge [these tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iseries%20or%20as400) into ibm-i and alias the three together (since IBM-i is the current brand name, while AS/400 is the brand most widely used and recognized by programmers for this platform) on SO, and alias the 3 tags together for future.

It's a real pain to have to remember to (a) supply all three in a search, and (b) tag questions with all three.  Luckily, no one seems to have used "system-i", or "systemi" yet.  Also when aliasing arrives, we need "os400", "i5os", "ibm-i" and "ibmi" linked with these.  See, I told you IBM lost it.

#### EDIT 2010-07-22

I retagged the three questions named i5 to IBM-i.  There are 93 and 125 questions tagged iSeries and as400, respectively.  I also updated this question to reflect this.

Comment: Wait, isn't `[i5]` a processor?

Comment: @mmyers: You'd think so, wouldn't you? But, no, or as well, it's one of IBM's names (maybe the current one, but I loose track) for the AS/400 system.

Comment: quick, elect a mod who knows wth this guy is talking about.

Comment: @Will: It's pretty simple - IBM have assigned about 6 different names to the AS/400 system over the years, which makes searching very difficult.  I am requesting that tags for several variant names of the platform be merged.

Comment: Editing to bump. These can be aliased now, but I'd like to get independent confirmation first.

Comment: It was originally OS/400, then i5/OS, then ix.x. It's now simply called "i" followed by the version number, though it's also referred to by "IBM i" and "System i". The current release is "i7.1". Software Monkey is correct, except that "iSeries" is a line of x86 powered servers.

Comment: @Chris: iSeries is definitely used by IBM to refer to the AS/400; it might be that iSeries is broader than just AS/400 and that specifically the "eServer iSeries" refers to the AS/400.

Comment: @Chris: Can you imagine branding your product with anything *less* searchable than a single letter, except perhaps rebranding it 7 or 8 times?

Comment: Intel has the i5 and i7 processors; how should they be distinguished?

Comment: @Will: We are not referring to the Intel processors (another reason why IBM's latest marketing branding of the AS/400 as simply "i" is asinine).  There are 3 questions tagged [i5] and all 3 relate to the AS/400 system.

Comment: @Software I know, but let's say I ask a question because I have a bug that only shows up on an i5 processor.  if [i5] means as/400, now we've got a problem.  Should [i5] be replaced with [ibm-i5] so that we can have [intel-i5]?  That might be the better solution... BRB, proposing an answer

Comment: Questions about IBM System i should be tagged "ibm-i" (or maybe "as400" since that's the historical name everyone knows). Questions about Intel's i3, i5, or i7 should be "intel-i#". I suppose it would be nice if we disallowed ambiguous tags like "i5" henceforth; but I think that'd be a PITA. I stand correct on the iSeries, they are indeed AS/400s only now; IBM started the xSeries moniker for their i386 based servers (what a headache).

Comment: @Chris: No, the historical name that "everybody" knows is AS/400.  It was that for two decades before it was IBM-i; in fact IBM-i has been the name for only about a couple of years, and, as I said, in the handful of years prior to that IBM renamed the system about 8 times.

Comment: @Software Monkey, neither capitals or slashes are allowed in tag names, so "as400" is as close as it gets. The name is still officially antiquated; I'm not suggesting we get rid of "as400", only that it should be aliased to "ibm-i" (the official name per the manufacturer).

Comment: @Chris: FWIW, xSeries was the name for Intel servers, and iSeries was the name for AS/400 servers; in the same way was zSeries was the name for mainframes and pSeries for AIX servers.  Seriously, but they have some real MPD going on in marketing.

Comment: It is possible people will want a specific name or version? Is it possible there's an issue (or any difference) with `i5os`, but not with `ibmi`? (for example, I don't understand anything either) If so, the tags might be useful.

Comment: @Kobi: No, as someone with over a 15 years with these systems I can say that's highly unlikely.  It should, anyway, be distinguished by the release version (VxRxMx) in the question, but not in any tag (while marketing are smoking something, IBM's technical people have done an amazing job on the technical aspect of the vision).

Answer (score 2):

How about we create [i5-ibm] [i7-ibm] and [i5-intel] [i7-intel] then alias as appropriate for [as400] etal (or vice versa)?

Aliasing [i5] to [as400] would screw anybody looking for the intel related tag.  And placing i5/i7 first will ensure intellisense pops up with both **ibm** and **intel** versions, so people will see the options and pick the relevant one...

Comment: I think this is the first time I see someone referring to the tag autocompletion as "intellisense".

Comment: @bal I'm a programmer, what can I say?

Comment: We could likely just merge the 3 i5 questions into AS400 and leave it at that, retagging the occasional i5's as they come along - i5 as a name for the AS/400 only lived for something like under a year.

Comment: Let's just pretend that IBM i5 never happened; as a brand it lived less than a year anyway.

Comment: My understanding from IBM was that i5 was never the platform name, just the name of a specific group of system hardware models released under the platform.  I believe at the time the platform was still named iSeries.  At the time I was an IBM Business Partner and it was hard for us even to understand what they thought the distinction was.

Comment: Just because no one brought it up yet: aren't the Intel processors called "Core i5" and "Core i7"? Wouldn't [core-i5] and [core-i7] be more appropriate tags, then?